# React Router v5 - element under nested route not displaying

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working on a project that uses React Router v5. My component, `HeatMapContainer`, is rendered from within a Switch like this:

```
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={LandingPage} />
            <Route path="/table" component={TablePage} />
            <Route path="/heatmap" component={HeatMapContainer} />
            <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
          </Switch>
```

I am attempting to create a nested Switch inside `HeatMapContainer` that will render different components based on the nested route. Inside `HeatMapContainer` I have this div:

```
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', width: '100%' }}>
        HEAT MAP CONTAINER
        <Link to="/heatmap/all">All</Link>
        <Route path="/heatmap/all" element={<AllOfficesRoute />} />
      </div>
```

Here is the `AllOfficesRoute` component I want to see upon clicking the Link:

```
function AllOfficesRoute() {
  return (
    <div className="all-offices-route">
      ALL OFFICES
    </div>
  );
}
```

Currently, the Link works and pushes the right path [ `/heatmap/all` ] onto history, but no component shows up. I started trying absolute paths because I distrusted relative paths, but even absolute paths don't seem to work here. Any help understanding what I'm missing would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be mixing RRDv5 and RRDv6 component API/syntax. If using RRDv5 the descendent route rendered by `HeatMapContainer` should render content on the `component` prop (*or `render` or `children` function props*) instead of a non-existent `element` prop.

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/table" component={TablePage} />
  <Route path="/heatmap" component={HeatMapContainer} />
  <Route path="/" exact component={LandingPage} />
  <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
</Switch>
```

HeatMapContainer

```
<div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', width: '100%' }}>
  HEAT MAP CONTAINER
  <Link to="/heatmap/all">All</Link>
  <Route path="/heatmap/all" component={AllOfficesRoute} />
</div>
```